# How to create horizontal bar chart with dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js

I managed to create some bar charts in dc.js:

[image]

My ordinal axis tick labels can become quite long. Therefore, I would like to show horizontal bars instead of vertical bars. This way, the long tick labels (e.g. "Price_Fuel", "Conventional", ...) would not need a tilt anymore.

Here is a d3 example for what I want:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_horizontal.html
[image]

I tried to replace calls like

```
barChart.x(d3.scaleBand())
```

with

```
barChart.y(d3.scaleBand())
```

but that did not help.

Furthermore, the bar chart does not seem to provide a direction property like

```
barChart.direction('horizontal')
```

=> How can I create horizontal bar charts with dc.js?

Some code snippet:

```
async __createBarChart(progressBar){

    let entries = await this.entries(this.__entry, progressBar);

    let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.__container);

    var barChart = dc.barChart(element)
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .margins({top:10,left:50,right:15,bottom:60})
        .barPadding(0.1)
        .transitionDuration(0)
        .outerPadding(0.1);

    let barColors =  ColorFactory.createColumnColors(this.__entry.letter, entries.length);
    FamilyChart.__defineBarColors(barChart, barColors);

    barChart
        //.xAxisLabel(this.__entry.label)
        .x(d3.scaleBand())
        .dimension(this.__dimension)
        .yAxisLabel(this.__yAxisLabel)
        .group(this.__group);

    barChart
        .xAxis()
        .tickFormat(id => this.__tickFormat(id, entries));

     dc.renderAll();

     return barChart;
}
```

Some CSS:

```
.family-chart-container svg .x.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

Comment: It’s a separate chart with very little code in common, and many subtle differences in features, called [dc.RowChart](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/RowChart.html). Many have tried and failed to merge the classes—in particular it doesn’t support stacking.